# Print out N by N Spiral Matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, interview-questions

I got this question during my practice interview.

### Matrices - N Spiral Matrix

#### Prompt

Given an integer N, output an N x N spiral matrix with integers 1 through N.

#### Examples:

```
Input:  3

Output: [[1, 2, 3],
         [8, 9, 4],
         [7, 6, 5]]

Input: 1

Output: [[1]]
```

My solution is below:

```
function spiralMatrix(n) {
  const matrix = [];
  let counter = 1,
    rowMin = 0,
    rowMax = n - 1,
    colMin = 0,
    colMax = n - 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix.push(new Array(n).fill(0));
  }

  while (rowMin <= rowMax && colMin <= colMax) {
    for (let col = colMin; col <= colMax; col++) {
      matrix[rowMin][col] = counter++;
    }
    rowMin++;
    for (let row = rowMin; row <= rowMax; row++) {
      matrix[row][colMax] = counter++;
    }
    colMax--;
    for (let col = colMax; col >= colMin; col--) {
      matrix[rowMax][col] = counter++;
    }
    rowMax--;
    for (let row = rowMax; row >= rowMin; row--) {
      matrix[row][colMin] = counter++;
    }
    colMin++;
  }

  return matrix;
}

console.log(spiralMatrix(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is well written;

**Comments**

- You have no comments whatsoever, fortunately the code reads well

**JSHint.com**

- Your code passes all checks, well done

Answer (score 2):

Nice code. I have just one nitpick.

No need to declare all variables at the top of a function.
It's good to declare variables right before they are used.
In the posted code, the filling of `matrix` could go directly after its declaration,
and the rest of the variables could be declared right before the loop that uses them.
I mean like this:

```
  const matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix.push(new Array(n).fill(0));
  }

  let counter = 1,
    rowMin = 0,
    rowMax = n - 1,
    colMin = 0,
    colMax = n - 1;

  while (rowMin <= rowMax && colMin <= colMax) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Do you have any references that say it is good to declare variables right before they are used? This does not seem to follow any major coding styles guide.

Comment: @konijn the book Code Complete takes about *span* and *live time* of variables. See it explained here: http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/books/programming/code-complete-2-steve-mcconnell-general-issues-using-variables/ . Keeping these numbers low mitigates the mental burden for readers.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `row`, and `col`, it is common to index a 2D array with `x` and `y`. `x` is column and `y` is row.

Rather than use `for` loops, you can reduce the noise using `while` loops inside the main loop.

The main exit condition is a little complex. You are counting the values with `counter` so why not just check its value `while(counter < n ** 2) {`

`colMax` and `rowMax` can be combined to just one value, same with `colMin`, and `rowMin`

The overhead of creating and filling each array before you start is negating the benefit of avoiding sparse arrays. The code would be simpler if you just push an array literal rather then a new n item array filled with 0.

Thus you end up with

```
function spiralMatrix(n) {
    var c = 1, min = 0, max = n - 1, x = 0, y = 0;
    const matrix = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) { matrix.push([]) }
    while (c < n ** 2) {
        while (x < max) { matrix[y][x++] = c++ }
        while (y < max) { matrix[y++][x] = c++ }
        while (x > min) { matrix[y][x--] = c++ }
        min++;
        while (y > min) { matrix[y--][x] = c++ }
        max--;
    }
    matrix[y][x] = c;
    return matrix;
}
```